# What does `public static <T> void main(String[] args)` stand for?

Tags: java

What does `public static <X> void main(String[] args)` stand for? I tried to understand but didn't get. I know about `public static void main(String[] arg)`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why downvoted? Nothing *wrong* with this *question*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at each bit in turn:

- `public` - it's a public method, accessible to anything which has access to the class in which this is declared
- `<X>` - this is (somewhat bizarrely) a generic method with an unbound type variable `X`
- `static` - the method is related to the type in which it's declared, not any specific *instance* of the type
- `void` - the method doesn't return a value
- `main` - the name of the method
- `String[] args` - a single parameter, of type `String[]` and called `args`

`main` is the entry point used by the JVM. When you run:

```
java foo.bar.Baz
```

it will try to find a `main` method in class `foo.bar.Baz`. I've never seen a generic `main` method before, admittedly. For more about generics in Java, read the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: so... What's the use of <X> ? Does it need to be declared in class level ? 
as in Baz<X> { ... } 
But the method is static, so don't need to new up an instance.
I don't see a way how the runtime can figure out the type of it.
Unless the method is public static <X> void main<X> (String[] args) {...}

Answer (score 4):

1. `<X>` is known as **Type Parameter**.
2. This is applicable to the methods, classes, variables, etc.. But its **most important use is to make the Collections more type safe.**
3. `<X>` will mark a **certain Type** within the `main()` method.
4. The whole sentence dissection is as follows:

   - `public` - is the access-modifier, means that this method is accessible from anywhere.
   - `<X>` - Type Parameter, as mentioned above
   - `void` - This method will not return anything
   - `main` - Method's name, main() method is the entry point of any pgm in java.
   - `String[]` : Array Of String.
   - `args`     : Array reference variabl of type String.